# Background image won't show in HTML Google

Tags: html, css

I put a background url in my CSS inside body and connected the CSS file to the html file, but nothing shows on google. I'm 100% sure I have the right path to the image. But the image is in the path I coded and I have no clue why it says file not found.

```
body  {
    background-image: url("/CSS/Images/barcelonastadium.jpg");
  }
```

***GET file:///C:/CSS/Images/barcelonastadium.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND***

That error shows in console log even tho the file exists.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title> Barcelona </title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='./CSS/home.css'>
</head>
<style>

</style>
<body>
    <h1> Barcelona </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: folder]

Comment: What's the structure of your project?

Comment: I just want to make a website about the football club barcelona

Comment: Try removing the `/` before `CSS`. Without your directory structure it isn't possible to be sure what the problem is.

Comment: Removed the "/" before "CSS" still same issue no image showing.

Comment: Welcome! You have the wrong path to the image, so the CSS can't find it. Is the `Images` folder inside of your `CSS` folder? Update your question to tell use where your CSS file is, and where your Images folder is. Edit: your HTML code won't help, since the error is from the actual directory (folder) structure. Your CSS is loading since you are getting the error, but you have the wrong path to the image

Comment: _I'm 100% sure I have the right path to the image._ You don't, since you are getting an error that the image can't be found.

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, you don't need `CSS` in the image path. Since you are referencing the `Images` folder in your `home.css` file - which is inside yoru CSS folder - it should be `Images/barcelonastadium.jpg`. Your path is wrong, because your CSS is looking for a CSS folder INSIDE of your CSS folder.

Comment: Voting to close as this is a typo.

Comment: Add a `./` before `Images`: `./Images/....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file path as seen in `GET file:///C:/CSS/Images/barcelonastadium.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` has two protocols in it: `file` and `C`. You should use a relative path in your CSS file instead, to avoid the confusion:

`./CSS/Images/barcelonastadium.jpg` or `./Images/barcelonastadium.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an absolute or relative path.

Here's a relative path:

```
body  {
  background-image: url("./Images/barcelonastadium.jpg");
}
```